# post-receive hook fails "cannot be used without a working tree"

Tags: git, git-checkout

I've used this Git setup for managing a website: http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto.

Things work, until I active the post-receive hook. Before activating it, I can push and pull with no problem. However, if I activate the hook, it says:

```
fatal: /usr/bin/git-checkout cannot be used without a working tree.
error: hooks/post-receive exited with error code 1
```

It still pulls properly, but does not copy the files as it is supposed to (to the webroot). But the post-receive hook reads:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/domains/mydomain/html/ git checkout -f
```

So why is git complaining about not having a work tree? The same syntax worked for other websites.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably be using `git archive` instead of `git checkout` for what it appears you're trying to do here (having a hook export the files to a web server's document root).

```
git archive HEAD | tar -xC /home/domains/mydomain/html/
```

One advantage this gives you is the ability to not export certain files from the repository (using the `.gitattributes` export-ignore flag).

Comment: how can you make this copy a specific branch (i.e. "master" or "test")?

Comment: Also; doing it this way destroys any filebits that may have been set.

Comment: The `HEAD` in the command is a name of a ref; you can use any ref you want (e.g. a branch name will also work)